# Resizing font size and padding using gd to create a dynamic bar chart

Tags: php, bar-chart, php-gd

Inspired by this [code](https://code.web-max.ca/image_graph.php), I am trying to create a simple bar chart able to dynamically create, resize both bars and texts depends on the the **$data**, **$height** and **$weight**:

```
<?php

$width = 300;
$height = 200;

$font_path = getenv('WINDIR') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "Fonts" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$font = 'arial.ttf';

$data = ['jan'=>30,'fev'=>40,'mar'=>90,'apr'=>77,
        'mai'=>33, 'jun'=>44, 'bigggggggg' => 80];

$columns = count($data);
$padding = ($width+$height)/100;

$column_width = $width / $columns;

$image = imagecreate($width, $height);
$gray = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$gray_lite = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xee, 0xee, 0xee);
$gray_dark = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);

imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $white);
$maxv = max($data);

$array_values = array_values($data);
$array_keys = array_keys($data);
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {

    $font_size = ($height / 100) * $padding;
    $column_height = ($height / 100) * (( $array_values[$i] / $maxv) * 100);
    $string = $array_keys[$i];

    $x1 = $i * $column_width;
    $y1 = $height - $column_height;
    $x2 = (($i + 1) * $column_width) - $padding;
    $y2 = $height - ($padding*4);
    $maxChars = ($font_size * 2) / $padding;

    if (strlen($string) > ($maxChars)) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, $maxChars) . '...';
    }

    imagefilledrectangle($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $gray);
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x1, $y2+$font_size+$padding, $black, $font_path.$font,
  $string);

    imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x1, $y2, $gray_lite);
    imageline($image, $x1, $y2, $x2, $y2, $gray_lite);
    imageline($image, $x2, $y1, $x2, $y2, $gray_dark);
}

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Using 300x200 its okay:

[image]

But using 600x400:

[image]

What Can I do to fix that?

Comment: ... or use [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only Font Size Calculations Which can be fixed earlier code:

```
$font_size = ($height / 100) * $padding;           //Changing this line
$column_height = ($height / 100) * (( $array_values[$i] / $maxv) * 100);
$string = $array_keys[$i];

$x1 = $i * $column_width;
$y1 = $height - $column_height;
$x2 = (($i + 1) * $column_width) - $padding;
$y2 = $height - ($padding*4);
$maxChars = ($font_size * 2) / $padding;
```

after changing it dynamic it would be as under:

```
$column_height = ($height / 100) * (( $array_values[$i] / $maxv) * 100);
$string = $array_keys[$i];

$x1 = $i * $column_width;
$y1 = $height - $column_height;
$x2 = (($i + 1) * $column_width) - $padding;
$y2 = $height - ($padding*4);
$font_size = ($x2 - $x1) / 4;                //Changed line and location
$maxChars = ($font_size * 2) / $padding;
```

**Except this change nothing is required.**

Answer (score 2):

You create the `$font_size` base on `$padding`, the `$font_size` will grow fast in the case size of chart grow

Instead of it, make the `$font_size` depend on the `$height` and `Y` position of the bars, it should work fine, please try this script instead

```
<?php

$width = 600;
$height = 400;

$font_path = getenv('WINDIR') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "Fonts" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$font = 'arial.ttf';

$data = ['jan'=>30,'fev'=>40,'mar'=>90,'apr'=>77,
        'mai'=>33, 'jun'=>44, 'bigggggggg' => 80];

$columns = count($data);
$padding = ($width+$height)/100;

$column_width = $width / $columns;

$image = imagecreate($width, $height);
$gray = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$gray_lite = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xee, 0xee, 0xee);
$gray_dark = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);

imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $white);
$maxv = max($data);

$array_values = array_values($data);
$array_keys = array_keys($data);
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {

    $column_height = ($height / 100) * (( $array_values[$i] / $maxv) * 100);
    $string = $array_keys[$i];

    $x1 = $i * $column_width;
    $y1 = $height - $column_height;
    $x2 = (($i + 1) * $column_width) - $padding;
    $y2 = $height - ($padding*4);
    $maxChars = ($font_size * 2) / $padding;

    if (strlen($string) > ($maxChars)) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, $maxChars) . '...';
    }
    $font_size = ($height - $y2) / 2.5;
    imagefilledrectangle($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $gray);
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x1, $y2+$font_size+$padding, $black, $font_path.$font,
  $string);

    imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x1, $y2, $gray_lite);
    imageline($image, $x1, $y2, $x2, $y2, $gray_lite);
    imageline($image, $x2, $y1, $x2, $y2, $gray_dark);
}

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Just small change on `$font_size = ($height - $y2) / 2.5;`

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: font_size in C:\wamp64\www\curso\gd\graphs\bar\webmax.php on line 38

Answer (score 1):

Try if this works.

Basically your font size was height/100 which was working when height was 200, but when you have doubled the height, we need to change the font size to match it as well.

See if this is the desired result [MaxInfo.Tech](https://www.maxinfo.tech/community/stackoverflow/58967622/chart.php)

```
<?php

$width = 600;
$height = 400;

$font_path = getenv('WINDIR') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "Fonts" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$font = 'arial.ttf';

$data = ['jan'=>30,'fev'=>40,'mar'=>90,'apr'=>77,
        'mai'=>33, 'jun'=>44, 'bigggggggg' => 80];

$columns = count($data);
$padding = ($width+$height)/100;

$column_width = $width / $columns;

$image = imagecreate($width, $height);
$gray = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$gray_lite = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xee, 0xee, 0xee);
$gray_dark = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);

imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $white);
$maxv = max($data);

$array_values = array_values($data);
$array_keys = array_keys($data);
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {

    $font_size = ($height / 200) * $padding;
    $column_height = ($height / 100) * (( $array_values[$i] / $maxv) * 100);
    $string = $array_keys[$i];

    $x1 = $i * $column_width;
    $y1 = $height - $column_height;
    $x2 = (($i + 1) * $column_width) - $padding;
    $y2 = $height - ($padding*4);
    $maxChars = ($font_size * 2) / $padding;

    if (strlen($string) > ($maxChars)) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, $maxChars) . '...';
    }

    imagefilledrectangle($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $gray);
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x1, $y2+$font_size+$padding, $black, $font_path.$font,
  $string);

    imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x1, $y2, $gray_lite);
    imageline($image, $x1, $y2, $x2, $y2, $gray_lite);
    imageline($image, $x2, $y1, $x2, $y2, $gray_dark);
}

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Also Please note to format it better you can change other variables also which are based on height or width, to something more dynamic than a static divider of 100.

Comment: some problems using 1200x800: https://i.imgur.com/N3MjigA.png